# I am facing issue in saving the model in .h5 format

Tags: tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning

[Here is my code for model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnbDs.jpg)
I picked up a pretrained model from keras application, and added some custom layers. And after training for custom dataset, I am facing issue in saving the model in .h5 format

[This is the issue am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0fgW.jpg).
Please help me fix this and save the model

Comment: Describe your problem in the question, ideally using minimal code, rather than posing links.

Comment: You can save a model with model.save() or keras.models.save_model() (which is equivalent). You can load it back with keras.models.load_model().

You can switch to the SavedModel format by:
     `Passing save_format='tf' to save()
       Passing a filename without an extension`
You can switch to the H5 format by:
    `Passing save_format='h5' to save()
      Passing a filename that ends in .h5`

Kindly refer this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/serialization_and_saving#how_to_save_and_load_a_model) to save a model in .h5 format.